# how to fix 'Uncaught Error: spawn ... EACCES' on travis

Tags: javascript, command-line, travis-ci

I'm trying to create a command line tool, but there is a problem when I run tests in travis:

[image]

code below:

```js
var assert = require("assert");
var path = require("path");
var exec = require("child_process").execFile;
var cmd = path.join(__dirname, "../lib", "serve.js");     // maybe this line
const { describe } = require("mocha");

var opts = {
  timeout: 5000,
  maxBuffer: 1024,
};

function exec_test(args, callback) {
  if (process.platform === "win32")
    exec(process.execPath, [cmd].concat(args), opts, callback);
  else exec(cmd, args, opts, callback);
}

describe("command line usage", function () {
  it("--version", function (done) {
    exec_test(["--version"], function (error, stdout, stdin) {
      assert(!error, error);
      assert(stdout.indexOf("livioo-live-server") !== -1, "version not found");
      done();
    });
  });
  
  ...

});
```

I guess it's because of lack of permission so I tried to add **before_install** like below:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- "14"
cache: yarn

before_install:                  +add
 - chmod +x ./                   +add

install:
  - yarn install

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: Build and test
      script:
        - yarn build
        - yarn test
```

However, I failed, got the same Error again

Does anyone know how to fix this Error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try replacing `chmod +x ./` with  `chmod -R 777 ./` ?